# Since ripple-lib-java is unmaintained, how do you manually sign a transaction?

Tags: kotlin, cryptocurrency, rippled

Looking for a lightweight way to manually sign an `OfferCreate` ... it would be clumsy to start some JavaScript engine in order to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm ... even though it hasn't been maintained for 4 years it looks like it still works.

Clone `ripple-lib-java` and do mvn install in `ripple-bouncycastle` & `ripple-core`

Then copy the built JARs into `<YourProject>/libs`

Add local dependencies in Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs("libs")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(":ripple-bouncycastle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation(":ripple-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")

    runtime("org.json:json:20190722") // No newskool kotlinx-serialization here :(
}
```

Create & sign OfferCreate:

```
val offerCreate = OfferCreate()
offerCreate.account(AccountID.fromString("r3jpWpUysF4SAkUNbG4WhDZ5mAJ7rGUDx6"))
offerCreate.expiration(UInt32(get2MinExpiration()))
offerCreate.fee(Amount(BigDecimal("0.00001")))
offerCreate.flags(UInt32(0))
offerCreate.sequence(UInt32(1))
val amountXRP = BigDecimal(200)
val amountBTC = convert(amountXRP, RIPPLE_XRP, BITCOIN)
offerCreate.takerGets(Amount(amountXRP))
offerCreate.takerPays(Amount(amountBTC, Currency.fromString(BITCOIN), AccountID.fromString(BITCOIN_TRUSTED_ISSUER)))
val signedTransaction = offerCreate.sign("[***Secret***]")
println(offerCreate.toJSON())
println(signedTransaction.tx_blob)
```

A bit annoying that you can't do a `toJSON()` on a `SignedTransaction`. It can
t be a security thing, since `sign()` only adds public key fields: https://xrpl.org/transaction-common-fields.html#signers-field

Comment: Duh ... when will I learn to read code ... ```signedTransaction.txn.toJSON()```